# How to restrict a user not to open a folder using vb.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to restrict a user from opening a sub folder like "permission denied" message should display while trying to open the folder. If yes, help me to solve this using vb.net in winform as well as using vb.net in asp.net

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about what you are trying to achieve and why the operating system permissions system isn't appropriate.

Comment: Actually i am creating one application for "Exam" module for both desktop and web using vb.net, where all the questions are seriliazed in binary file, if the user deletes them then the application will not execute, hence i do not want user will able to open the folder and trying to manipulate the file. Or any other options are there like compressing the file. etc. Pls. suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than try to restrict access to a folder, it may be easier to add your files as [embedded resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319291).  That way they will be part of your executable and the users won't be able to delete them.

Comment: +1 Embedded resources are nice since users can't mess with them easily.

Comment: @AndyWest But what if files needs to be dropped and execute ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the questions binary file into a sub folder and make it read only for any user except the administrators, this isn't a programming issue, it's an administration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, you have an interesting set of constraints.

For the web this is relatively straightforward and you can restrict user access to application/data files in any number of ways - this is (or ought to be) inherent in web servers/applications (its certainly baked into asp.net).

For a desktop application however its rather more interesting and it depends on how the application is to be installed/run - if the user has admin rights on the machine then there's very little you can do to stop them manipulating files. If they don't then you need an admin to deploy the application and you have a different set of interesting problems.

As you're looking for a solution to work on both platforms then I'd do as @Andy suggests the best solution is probably therefore to make the questions embedded resources - this won't necessarily stop a user deleting the file but it will make manipulating the content much harder, you can add a fingerprint (MD5 for example) and encryption into the mix too. If you want to be able to have different question sets you can just embed them into a separate .dll and there are various options for picking up the .dlls at runtime.